# Groovy to requests Jenkins Rest API with multi url encoding

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have curl command as given below, I need to run the same in Groovy script for Jenkins pipeline. How do I implement with multiple url encoded?

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/accounts/api/v2/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=234htryjbd97bkjkjkls0099kjkbjb' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=9987657884yterws87654hjkjhhvj' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

I have used groovy with body as for Jenkins pipeline as:

```
def jsonBody = '{"userName": "' + myusername +'" ,"password": "' + mypassword + '" }'
def token =  httpRequest consoleLogResponseBody: false, contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', httpMode: 'POST', httpProxy: 'http:// myproxy.someone.com:8080', requestBody: jsonBody, url: 'https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/accounts/api/v2/oauth2/token', wrapAsMultipart: false
def cont = new JsonSlurper().parseText(token.content)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to [mule doc](https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/portals/anypoint-platform/f1e97bc6-315a-4490-82a7-23abe036327a.anypoint-platform/access-management-api/minor/1.0/pages/Authentication/) the oauth/token request could be plain json:

```
POST /accounts/oauth2/token HTTP 1.1
Host: anypoint.mulesoft.com
Content-Type: application/json

{
   "client_id" : "123456789",
   "client_secret": "123456789",
   "grant_type" : "client_credentials"
}
```

so, your code could be like this:

```
def jsonBody = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(
    client_id:     '234htryjbd97bkjkjkls0099kjkbjb',
    client_secret: '9987657884yterws87654hjkjhhvj',
    grant_type:    'client_credentials'
).toPrettyString()

def token =  httpRequest(
  consoleLogResponseBody: false, 
  contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', 
  httpMode: 'POST', 
  httpProxy: 'http:// myproxy.someone.com:8080', 
  requestBody: jsonBody, 
  url: 'https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/accounts/api/v2/oauth2/token', 
  wrapAsMultipart: false
)
```

Comment: I found another approach given below, which one is better approach?

Answer (score 0):

another approach

```
final def(String tokenResponse, int code) = sh(script: "#!/bin/sh -e\n \
        curl -w '\\n%{response_code}' --location --request POST 'https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/accounts/api/v2/oauth2/token' \
        --proxy 'http://myproxy.someone.com:8080' \
        --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
        --data-urlencode 'client_id=${client_id}' \
        --data-urlencode 'client_secret=${secret}' \
        --data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials'", returnStdout: true).trim().tokenize("\n")
    if(code != 200){
        throw new Exception("=== UnAuthorized --> " + tokenResponse)
    }else{
       // Continue furtther
    }
```